# Multiple implementations for a psycopg2 cursor

Tags: python, psycopg2

How can I mix cursor implementations in `psycopg2`? In my case I want the cursor to act both as a `NamedTupleCursor` and a `LoggingCursor`.

Comment: You need the one cursor to have both behaviours or can you have two cursors for the same connection, one of each kind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently not, I've committed just a few days ago [a patch](https://github.com/dvarrazzo/psycopg/commit/9f9da182f1d5c188c306161f8b96263ce333168b) to enable cooperative subclassing.

The logging cursor is nothing special, it's more a demo than something really useful: I suggest you to subclass the NamedTupleCursor and add the logging statements you need, taking a look at the LoggingCursor as a hint.

Comment: I don't know what version was current when @piro wrote this answer, but as of psycopg 2.5.1 it's possible (thanks to his patch).

Answer (score 2):

For the record, with @piro patch is possible using a Mixin:

```
from psycopg2.extras import LoggingConnection,LoggingCursor,RealDictCursor

class MixinLoggedDictCursor(LoggingCursor, RealDictCursor):
   pass

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    cursor_factory=MixinLoggedDictCursor,
    connection_factory=LoggingConnection,
    **kwargs
)
conn.initialize(my_logger)
```